# Derivative of multivariable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}^n, f(x)=g(\|x\|)x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Derivative of multivariable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to
>  \mathbb{R}^n, f(x)=g(\|x\|)x$

My attempt: I used the product and chain rule.

$$J_f(x)=x\cdot g'(\|x\|)\cdot \frac{1}{\|x\|}\cdot x+g(r)I_n$$

The solution says it's $J_f(x)=g'(r)\frac{1}{\|x\|}xx^T+g(r)I_n$

why do we have $xx^T$? Why the transpose?

Comment: To produce a literal backslash in the output, type in `\backslash`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful when you write the dot where you really mean matrix multiplications. If $x$ is a column vector, $xx^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix; but $x^Tx$ is not. In any case, $xx$ does not make sense and $x\cdot x$ would be a scalar if you do inner product.

You may work on the case when $n=2$ and write everything in terms of components to see what happens.